# data being over-written. Android

Tags: android

I am reading data from a sensor into two static double []'s called Gain and Phase. Then depending on what button the user pressed to start collecting data from the sensor, I save this data to another double [].

Ex:

```
    if (What_Button == 1){
        oGain = gain;
        oPhase = phase;
        output.setText("OPEN saved");
    }
    if (What_Button == 2){
        sGain = gain;
        sPhase = phase;
        output.setText("SHORT saved");
    }
    if (What_Button == 3){
        lGain = gain;
        lPhase = phase;
        output.setText("LOAD saved");
    }
```

I then wish to plot the original Gain and Phase data.  Before I do this I convert the gain into dB and the phase into degrees.

i.e.

```
 for (int i=0; i<_steps; i++) {
    phase[i]=Math.toDegrees(phase[i]);
    gain[i]=20*Math.log10(gain[i]);
    }
```

This plotting works fine but after gain and phase have been converted my saved data "lgain" "lphase", etc are changed.  It is as if they have been reassigned to the new Gain and Phase values instantly.  I surrounded the code above with System.out.pritln commands to view the lgain, lphase, etc. values before and after and this is certainly where they are being changed at.  I used ctrl-f to find all instances of lgain, lphase, etc and they are not being reassigned anywhere else.  Any ideas how to fix this?

C

Comment: Show more code, what's around the ifs?

Comment: You're not copying the data, you're copying references, so it's the same array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying phase array by reference rather than value.

Try looking at [Arrays.CopyOf](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html) documentation to choose a static method to copy the array.

Something like:

```
oGain = Arrays.copyOf(gain,gain.length);
```